Apache HttpClient 4.x - PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager keeps on calling requestConnection()
Turning on DEBUG level logging for PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager, I see my application is requesting connection over and over, printing logs like:
13:49:11,360 DEBUG [com.example.app.MyClass$1](main) Connection request: [route: {}->http://localhost:40429][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 200; total allocated: 0 of 200]
13:49:11,360 DEBUG [com.example.app.MyClass$1](main) Connection leased: [id: 1][route: {}->http://localhost:40429][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 200; total allocated: 1 of 200]
13:49:11,361 DEBUG [com.example.app.MyClass$1](main) Connection released: [id: 1][route: {}->http://localhost:40429][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 200; total allocated: 0 of 200]

Why it's requesting over and over again?
I also observe it during application start up time, before even any routes is established, it keeps requesting connection.
